# Laplace calculation

Tags: calculus

it posible to find $$\int_0^{\infty } e^{s (-x)} \sec (x) \, dx$$
Thanks
 I think this integral is not convergent in the Cauchy sense but it is possible calculated a regulated laplacetransform that justify a type of analityc extension for example the transform $$\mathcal{L}_x\left[\frac{1}{x^2}\right](s)$$ you would say that do not exit but it can be show that exits what do you think about it?

Comment: Not really; there are poles when $x=(2 k+1) \pi/2$ for integer $k$.

Comment: The Maple command $$int(exp(-s*x)*sec(x), x = 0 .. infinity, 'CauchyPrincipalValue') assuming s > 0 $$ produces $$1/2\,i \left( -\Psi \left( -1/4\,i \left( s+3\,i \right)  \right) +
\Psi \left( -1/4\,i \left( s+i \right)  \right) +{\frac {\pi }{\cosh
 \left( 1/2\,\pi \,s \right) }} \right)
 .$$

Comment: hi great i have not maple but icould calculate $$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{e^{s (-x)} \sin ^3(x)}{x^3} \, dx=\frac{1}{16} i \left(2 i s^2 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{s-2 i}\right)+6 i s \log (s-3 i)+6 i s \log (s+3 i)+9 \log (s-3 i)-9 \log (s+3 i)+6 i (s-i)^2 \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{s}\right)\right)$$ using $$\mathcal{L}_x\left[\frac{1}{x^2}\right](s)$$ that wolfram alpha do not